# Did Edwards pass the MiB test?

Tags: men-in-black

In [Men In Black (1997)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119654/?ref_=nv_sr_2), K tells Edwards to come to the MiB building where he ends up with a few members from different branches of the military. They're all there to take a test to join the MiB. What I don't understand is if it was really a test for everyone or just for Edwards. If it wasn't just for Edwards, did he pass or did K influence Zed into choosing him?

I was wondering if Edwards had passed or not because during the written test, he pulled the table over so he could write on it and in the shooting test, he shot the little girl, but gave a great explanation of why. Were these things what Zed was looking for in a candidate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He had to have passed the tests or he wouldn't have been an agent.  These aren't real tests, they're *psyche* tests. Presented with a problem, how do you solve it?  The tests are conducted in a way that conformists, with no imagination or natural problem-solving ability, will give predictable results. Only the most perceptive candidate will pass by applying logic even when the logical conclusion deviates from standard behavior.

While he may not have the academic credentials of the other candidates, he demonstrates that he can undertake completely unfamiliar situations and use his "street" abilities to meet them in unexpected ways.

Comment: So his actions did in fact cause him to pass the test then, it wasn't just him being funny.

Comment: I think they used comedy in both tests, but I also think it was definitely meant to show that he can "think outside the box", because dealing with aliens is definitely not something that is a normal occurrence for normal individuals.  Also, as I said, he had to have passed or he wouldn't be an agent.

Comment: Right, but I was asking if he passed because he passed the tests or if he was accepted because of K's influence on Zed. But, you answered my question to that point.